# Find the single wrong element in matrix product?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Three N*N matrices A,B,C are given. C is the same as the product of A and B except that exactly one element is wrong. The naive algorithm to find it out requires N^3 time. Can we do faster than that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a vector `v = (1 1 1 1 ... 1)T`, and calculate: `u = Cv - A(Bv)`.

`u` is equal to `(C-AB)v`, and therefore it will have zeroes in all elements except one. The index of this element corresponds to the row index where C is different from AB. The value of the element (`a`) is the value of the nonzero element in `C-AB`.

To find the column index, you can repeat this with the vector `v2 = (1 2 3 4 ... n)T`. Now the value of the nonzero element is `ac`, where `a` is the value we calculated before and `c` is the column index.

Since we only do a few matrix*vector multiplications, the running time is O(n^2).